# What's the difference between the Int() method and Math.Floor() methods in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, random, int, floor

I'm trying to generate positive random integers between 2 values and the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx) lists this formula as generating random numbers between a certain range:
`randomValue = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerbound`.
The page later lists an example that appears to use Int() intstead of Math.Floor():
`Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1))`.
Is there any difference between the Int method and Math.Floor in this situation?

Comment: What does the msdn says in that page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Int() is the legacy function that existed in VB before .NET came around.

Source is not included in the Reference Source, but a decent decompiler can show you what it does.  Navigate to the Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion class to see:

```
public static double Int(double Number)
{
    return Math.Floor(Number);
}
```

No surprises, use what ever flavor you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the breakdown...

```
    CInt(0.1)  -----> 0
    CInt(0.7)  -----> 1
    CInt(-0.1) -----> 0
    CInt(-0.7)  -----> -1

    Int(0.1)  -----> 0.0
    Int(0.7)  -----> 0.0
    Int(-0.1) -----> -1.0
    Int(-0.7)  -----> -1.0

    Math.Floor(0.1)  -----> 0.0
    Math.Floor(0.7)  -----> 0.0
    Math.Floor(-0.1) -----> -1.0
    Math.Floor(-0.7) -----> -1.0
```

Or if you prefer, **CInt** is more like **Math.Round**, while floor is NEXT LOWEST INTEGER.. Note that's **NOT** Next closest to zero.

**Int** is like Floor, but [Floor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a6a2sxy(v=vs.110).aspx) only accepts types **Decimal** or **Double**, where as [Int](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kc0af4(v=vs.110).aspx) has more overloads.

Either way, you would need to coerce them again into an integer.

Comment: `CInt()` <> `Int()`

Comment: Thanks @GSerg for pointing that out, I updated my answer for completeness.,

Comment: It's not about completeness, it makes the "quite a bit" bit wrong. The outer `CInt` is not relevant, only the inner `Int` is, and as [Hans Passant noticed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42515849/11683), it's the same as `Math.Floor`.

Comment: Ya, I know, I misread the initial point of the question... @Gserg, was already corrrecting it.

Comment: Wondering why floor returns Decimal... not double. But then again, not really LOL.

Comment: It does both (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7ycc7xh(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The text of the answer implies that Int() returns an integer, which is incorrect.  It returns a Double.  Results should be shown as 0.0 and -1.0 like Floor to avoid confusion.  Option Strict will squawk if you try to stuff the result of Int() into an integer type.

Comment: @Craig, thanks. Oddly Int is also overloaded with integer types, though the wording in MSDN contradicts itself for those.